# How to limit the number of characters shown in an input that has a lot more characters in it in CSS

Tags: css, input-field

I have an input fields that's a specific width. It can hold up to 14 characters total, but I want it to only show as many as 3. Can't seem to find an answer online. Is it even possible? Because if I have 888, part of the 3rd 8 is cut off. And if I have 1111, part of the 4th 1 is visible. And I can't cover it with margins or paddings. And I don't want to cover it with another element if it's possible to adjust the number of items displayed.

[3rd 8 is cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ir6d.png)
[4th 1 is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIeCe.png)

```
input {
margin-top: 30px;
background: none;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: azure;
border-radius: 15px;
height: 80px;
width: 80px;
font-size: 50px;
text-align: center;
color: azure;
outline: none;
transition: 0.2s;
padding-inline: 10px;
font-family: monospace;
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried. And have you used a monospace font and a width based on the ch unit?

Comment: Have a look at the reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text It describes the various attributes such as maxlength. I find setting the font-family to for example Courier, monospace and the style to have width something like 3.2ch works OK.

Comment: maxlength allows more characters in the fields, that's there, the field can hold 14 characters max. My issue is a visual one. As you can see from my 2 screenshots. My issue is that 3 8's don't fully fit into the allowed space that the user can see and 4 1's fit too close and thus a small piece of the 4th 1 is showing.

Comment: Is there a piece of code to make an input display only 3 out of 14 characters? Changing font doesn't help. Margins and paddings don't work, spacing didn't work. I can't make it so when i have 888 I see them fully and when I have 1111 to not see the last one sticking out.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. Have you tried setting size and styling width and using a monospace font as in my comment? Please show us the code you have tried.

Comment: OHHHHHH, monospace characters are all the same width. This can work. Not the best looking font for me personally, but it fits nicely. Thank you! Still, there is no code to adjust how many characters an input field is showing, right?

Comment: I already suggested width using the ch unit. Did you try that,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various attributes and CSS settings which can help.

This snippet sets the font-family to a monospace font so each of the characters has the same width. There are various different monospace fonts available if you don't like the look of Courier or are worried that another local font may be picked up.

The input element width is set via CSS to the total number of characters (3), using the ch CSS unit. This allows for just 3 characters to be seen.

The total number of characters that the user is allowed to input is more than this (14) and is set using an attribute.

```html
<input maxlength="14" type="text" style="width: 3ch; font-family: Courier, monospace; padding: 0;">
```

Comment: This will do perfectly. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use,

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
max-width: ?px;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).